Reducing a system matrix by unitary transforms, but preserving zeros
I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 1 in the paper "Computation of Zeros of Linear Multivariable Systems" by Emami-Naeini and Van Dooren.
The idea is to construct a reduced form of a system matrix, while preserving the same zeros as the original system matrix. The authors of the paper do this with unitary transform matrices $V_j$ and $U_j$:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} V_j^* & 0 \\ 0 & U_j^*\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \lambda I_{\nu_{j-1}}-A_{j-1} & B_{j-1}\\ -C_{j-1} & D_{j-1}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}V_j & 0\\0 & I_m\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda I_{\nu_{j}}-A_{j} & * & B_j \\ -C_j & * & D_j\\ 0 & -S_j & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Where $S_j$ has full column rank. The authors then claim that the system matrix for $A_j, B_j, C_j, D_j$ has the same zeros as the original $A_{j-1}, B_{j-1}, C_{j-1}, D_{j-1}$.
Now, for my question: how exactly does this keep the same zeros as the original system?
I know that the zeros are the values of $\lambda$ that make the system drop from its normal rank. I also understand that the unitary matrix transforms "compress" $C_{j-1}, D_{j-1}$ into full row/column rank sub-matrices.
What I do not understand is the columns in the right hand side with $S_j$: why do we just "get rid" of these columns? The rows with $D_j$ are full row-rank I guess. But as far as I can tell, basically $\lambda I_{\nu_{j-1}} - A_{j-1}$ get split into $\lambda I_{\nu_{j}} - A_j$ and some other set of columns $*$: why don't these "$*$" columns contain useful information about the rank of the first rows, why are we allowed to discard them?
It's possibly my question doesn't really make sense, I am not entirely sure the best way to ask it, as I'm not very well versed in this topic - any ideas or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

If I am not mistaken, the proof for that is given in the paper you mention.
